# Building existing eclipse project with maven tool

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

I am new to maven tool. I have a java project on RAD 7.0.Compiling the project and building jar with RAD 7.0 taking huge time. So to remove the time wastage we planed to use maven 2.

we are not permitted to change the application structure and package structure. Please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep application structure, you just have to parametrize correctly the pom.xml that describe the project.

In your pom.xml, you'll have to add all dependencies included in your classpath and project structure (sourceDirectory, testDirectory) via plugins

You can find some samples in the older post :
[How to create the pom.xml for a java project with Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817885/how-to-create-pom-xml-for-java-projec-using-eclipse)