# Migration of PDE Build to CBI (Common Build Infrastructure)

Tags: eclipse, maven, ant, eclipse-pde, pde

Since Eclipse CBI (Common Build Infrastructure)is coming into picture, we would migrate like to migrate to it from existing PDE Build system (based on ANT).

So how can we do the migration easily?

Do we need to create POM.xml file for each plugin, can it be generated automatically?

Could we still use the existing ANT scripts?

How the target platform would be created, is it just Maven repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are maven plugins in existence that will auto-generate POM files from eclipse plugins. There are other example questions about that, [How to create the pom.xml for a java project with Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8817885/713646)

You can still use some existing ant scripts if you have to, using the [maven-antrun-plugin](http://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.framework.git/tree/features/org.eclipse.equinox.executable.feature/pom.xml#n28) artifact or the [tycho-eclipserun-plugin](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator.git/tree/eclipse-platform-parent/pom.xml#n608) artifact.

The target platform is created by filling in the repositories section with repos that have a layout of p2 (so they can be consumed by tycho).

[Tycho](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Reference_Card) is a good place to get started.