# How to create pom.xml based on the jars in the project?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, pom.xml

I am working on this project which is way behind. They have not used maven or any build process. We decided to go with maven. Is there any way with which I can create pom.xml from the jars?

Comment: Shouldn't take that long.  Get a shovel and start editing your pom.xml.  If you are good with a scripting language for your OS perhaps you can use that to get started.  But you'll need each individual <dependency> entry in Maven Central.  No automating that.

Comment: If this projects happens to be an Eclipse Project you should check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817885/how-to-create-the-pom-xml-for-a-java-project-with-eclipse

Answer (score 4):

Assumed that you have some legacy jar files from previous work and those projects do not make use of Maven

Now, you want to build a new project using those jar files with the usage of Maven.

You can consider to install those jar files into your local repository by Maven command

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.yourcompany -DartifactId=yourartifactid -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dfile=yourfile.jar -DgeneratePom=true
```